# sql query to get co-incidence actions by two users for each other

Tags: mysql, sql

i am making a system in which there is a co-incidence for eg suppose user 1 clicks on button of user2 and both user's name is saved in database and if the user 2 also clicks on user 1 button(where users 2 is the same user that user 1 clicked on and in second case user 1 is the same user that clicked user 1 in first case). then how to filter out those two users who gave action one to each other ?

```
user 1  user 2 action 

 frank  ron     1

  ron  frank    1
```

such that it tells that there is a coincidence since both gave action to each other

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.something = x.something_else AND y.something_else... oh you get the idea...

Comment: they are not two different tables but one table

Comment: And your point is...?

Comment: suppose you and i are user 1 and and 2 . i login and click on a button below your profile pic . it would save to database as user 1 (me) gave action 1 to user 2 (you). you login and you also did the same . so there is a coincidence so i wan to that co incidence in database as it has both the records of us how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do that.

Since you didn't provide any SQL DDL, I'll add some. (Include DDL in the future. You'll get more answers.)

```
create table test (
  user_1 varchar(15) not null,
  user_2 varchar(15) not null,
  action integer not null,
  primary key (user_1, user_2, action)
);

insert into test values
('frank', 'ron', 1),
('ron', 'frank', 1  );

-- This is a one-way action. It should be excluded from the results.
insert into test values
('ron', 'fred', 1);

insert into test values
('ron', 'fred', 2),
('fred', 'ron', 2);
```

This will return pairs of rows for each match.  It's not a particularly good way to express this query, because the pairs won't directly sort together.

```
select t1.user_1, t1.user_2, t1.action
from test t1
inner join test t2 
        on t2.user_1 = t1.user_2 
       and t2.user_2 = t1.user_1
       and t2.action = t1.action

USER_1    USER_2  ACTION
--
frank     ron       1
fred      ron       2
ron       frank     1
ron       fred      2
```

If you tried to sort that result set, you could end up with a lot of names between 'frank' and 'ron'. It's hard to see that this data has the right answer.

This query returns a single row for each matched pair.

```
select user_1, user_2, action
from test
where user_1 < user_2
union all 
select user_2, user_1, action
from test 
where user_2 < user_1
group by user_1, user_2, action
having count(action) = 2

USER_1  USER_2  ACTION
frank   ron      1
fred    ron      2
```

It creates the union of two proper subsets of the original table. In each row, the first column is "less than" the second column. This has the effect of manufacturing duplicate rows. A duplicate row means the each user has "actioned" the other. The GROUP BY and HAVING clauses eliminate one-way actions.